# adding a figure to a sum query output

Tags: mysql

is it possible to add a value to a select sum statements output?

i have a query that is summing a field based on the year, however i need the year 2022 to have an additional value of 1500 added to the sum.

```
SELECT YEAR(rcyl_in) as Year, 
        SUM(case when a_RECLM.kgs_cred > a_RECLM.net_wt then a_RECLM.net_wt/2
                  else a_RECLM.kgs_cred/2 end) as 'Total Recovered'
FROM a_reclm  
GROUP BY  YEAR(rcyl_in)
```

result

```
2019    49208.450000
2020    11014.900000
2021    34092.400000
2022    1094.800000
```

however I need 2022 to be 2594.80000

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is apply an outer query with another case condition.

Below query is not tested, try and let me know:

```
SELECT Year,case when Year=2022 then Total_Recovered+1500 else Total_Recovered end as new_Total_Recovered
FROM (
         SELECT YEAR(rcyl_in) as Year, 
                SUM(case when a_RECLM.kgs_cred > a_RECLM.net_wt then a_RECLM.net_wt/2
                          else a_RECLM.kgs_cred/2 end) as 'Total_Recovered'
         FROM a_reclm  
         GROUP BY  YEAR(rcyl_in)
      ) as t1 ;
```

Comment: thanks for the responce however it is not displaying the results of the query correctly  but is also adding the 1500 to the year not the result.

2017 2017
2018 2018
2019 2019
2020 2020
2021 2021
2022 3522

Comment: @thomas my mistake I multiply the year not the Total_Recovered, check the updated answer

Comment: thank you! much appreciated. the updated works great